# Problem with custom datepicker in Chrome and safari

Tags: jquery, css, google-chrome

I have a problem with chrome and safari ..the date picker is not opening while clicking on the button. I set the calander image as the background of the button 
 here is my code

html:

```
input type="button" id="startdate" src="../images/Calendar.png" class="actions-edit-task task-exp-callendar">
```

Jquery:

```
$('#startdate').datepick({

        onSelect : showStartDate
    });

function showStartDate(dates) {
    var sdate = dates[0];
    taskStartDate = new Date(sdate.toDateString() + " " + $('#hourselector').val() + ":" + $('#minutselector').val() + " " + $('#ampmselector').text()).getTime();
}
```

CSS:

```
.actions-edit-task{
float: left;
padding: 5px;
margin: 5px 5px 0 5px;
}
.task-exp-callendar{
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    background-image: url('../images/Calendar.png');
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you given your input two classes?

```
class="actions-edit-task task-exp-callendar">
```

Combine the CSS/JS into one class, see if this makes any difference. Safari and Chrome are "future browsers" perhaps they have trouble reading both classes.

HTML

```
<input type="button" id="startdate" src="../images/Calendar.png" class="combined-class">
```

CSS

```
.combined-class {
height: 20px;
width: 20px;
background-image: url('../images/Calendar.png');
float: left;
padding: 5px;
margin: 5px 5px 0 5px;
}
```